# Setting up a timer event in a prototype using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a hard time getting a countdown timer working as I don't know what I am doing wrong.  I am trying to setup a countdown timer using jQuery in a prototype.

The main problem I see so far is at the setInterval:

```
_self.counter = setInterval(_self.runTimer(_self),1000);
```

When I don't pass in the "this" I get NaN but when I do the countdown only happens once and then stops.

Here is my JSFiddle work so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/f9GN7/

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `_self.runTimer(_self)` doesn't do what you think it does. It runs once, and returns `undefined` to `setInterval`. You want to pass it the function instead: `setInterval(_self.runTimer, 1000)`

Comment: When I do that it just send NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified a little of your code, I changed setInterval to setTimeout.

```
var timer_code = function(){
    this.counter;
    this.timeCountDown = 30;
}

timer_code.prototype = {
    init : function(){
        var _self = this;
        $('#start').on('click',function(e){
            _self.setTimer();
        });
    },

    setTimer : function(){
        var _self = this;
        // _self.counter = setInterval(_self.runTimer(_self),1000);
        var timerLoop = function(){
            if(_self.timeCountDown > 0){
                _self.runTimer();
                setTimeout(timerLoop, 1000);
            }
        };
        timerLoop();
    },

    runTimer : function(){
        var _self = this;
        _self.timeCountDown--;
        if(_self.timeCountDown <= 0){
        //    clearInterval(_self.counter);
            $('#timer').html("DONE");
            return;
        }
        $('#timer').html(_self.timeCountDown);
        console.log(_self.timeCountDown);
    }
}

var timer = new timer_code();
timer.init();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9GN7/1/

Comment: [Why you should use setTimeout rather than setInterval](http://warp.byu.edu/site/content/1117)

Answer (score 0):

setInterval gets a function reference as its first parameter ..

This function may not return a function object, the function call you just passed needs to be called in the scoope of a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Keeping your code with just a few modifications :

```
setTimer: function(){
    if(this.counter)
    clearInterval(this.counter); // timer may have already been launched, it may need to be cleared if its value is an integer and is != 0
    this.counter = setInterval(
    (function (ref) {
        return function () {
            ref.runTimer();
        }
    })(this),
    1000);
}
```

See [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/e4eeV/)